# rails_admin get the current entity and display custom enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm trying to customize an enum field with something else than only the name.

For example my entity record from database have columns as: name, postal_code, id etc ..

and I would like to have something like this in the dropdown "`#{name} #{postal_code}, #{department}`

I'm doing this:

```
field :city, :enum do
  enum do
    # Here I would like to get the entity from DB in order to have all 
    # columns to something similar as => 
      entity.collect.each { |c| "#{c.name} (#{c.postal_code}), # 
      {c.department.name}"}
  end
end
```

but I don't know how to get the active records (entity in my example) of the actual value of City entity.

How can I do this?

note: that department belongs to another model who is associated to City

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the OP comments i'm going to asume that the model in question has this association defined like this:

```
belongs_to :city
```

And the city field itself something like this

```
rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :city
  end
end
```

Because this way rails admin will render a select drop down that will allow you to search the cities without loading them all.

After that on the City model you can define the title method, quoting [the docs](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Models#the-object_label_method-method)

By default it tries to call "name" or "title" methods on the record in question. If the object responds to neither, then the label will be constructed from the model's classname appended with its database identifier. You can add label methods (or replace the default [:name, :title]) with:

```
RailsAdmin.config {|c| c.label_methods << :rails_admin_title }
```

The title method can then be defined

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
   def rails_admin_title
      "#{self.name} (#{self.postal_code}), #{self.department.name}"
   end 
end
```

In a related issue, you will probably want to configure how rails admin searches for the city, i'll [just link to the docs](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List#fields-searching).

Comment: I manage to call the method in my model, but for an unknow reason I can't have the current City entity. This is what I have in **rails_admin.rb**
    ```object_label_method do
      :rails_admin_title
    end```  
***inside my model***
```def rails_admin_title
      "#{self.city.name} (#{self.city.postal_code})"
end```

but **self** is just my current model with null value for each columns

Comment: It will use that method also for new instances, so you need to output a default value for new cities, just check inside that method if self.new_record? and return some string that does not depend on any value being set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you need to define a name and a (stable)value for each select drop down, a simple hash out to do it like this:

```
  field :city, :enum do
    enum do
      entity = bindings[:object]
      City.all.map do |c| 
        {c.id => "#{c.name} (#{c.postal_code}), #{c.department.name}"}
      end
    end
  end
```

Im assuming each city has an id, but you can use any value you want to store on that field on your DB.

So your users would see the nice formatted string, but rails admin would post the form with the city id on the city field.